# Accessing Azure B2C Access Token with Sitecore ID Server

Tags: azure, identity-server, azure-ad, azure-b2c

In Sitecore 9.1 we have integrated Azure B2C with Sitecore Identity Server. We now need to get access to the Azure B2C Access Token on the Sitecore CD server, which was based to Sitecore Identity Server.

Is this possible? How do I configure the Sitecore Identity Server to pass the token through to the Sitecore CD server?

Comment: I am taking a guess here , Can you not append the token in query string , when you are redirecting back to CD server ?